Issues Deploying KMDF Hello World Driver
Currently I'm following microsofts kmdf hello world tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/gettingstarted/writing-a-very-small-kmdf--driver.
Right now I am able to compile the driver, but am unable to deploy it.
In VSCode 2022 when I go to:
Configuration Properties -> Driver Install -> Deployment 
I get an error(Img of Error).
If I check my installed extensions, it says that the WDK extension is installed.
If I go to View -> Toolbars, driver toolbar is also enabled.
Please let me know if anyone has any ideas, or if more information is needed, thanks!

I just ended up deploying it manually, still couldn't figure out how to do it through vscode though.
